# Как стилизовать курсор средствами CSS?

Tags: html, css

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    cursor: url(../img/Cursor/Cursor_Goth_Cursor4.png), auto;
    
}
```

Назначил через css ко всей странице свой курсор, всё отлично, но при наведении на текст, ссылки или закрывающие страницу элементы, курсор меняется на стандартный, как сделать так, чтобы он не менялся ни в каком случае, а оставался кастомным. И есть ли возможность реализовать такое не используя js.
p.s: кстати только заметил, что курсор при наведении на текст не меняется, только при наведении на видео и закрывающие страницу элементы.
[image: Кстати вот сам курсор]

p.s.s: Попробовал такой способ, ничего не вышло, все также

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    cursor: url(../img/Cursor/Cursor_Goth_Cursor4.png), auto;

}
*:hover{
    cursor: url(../img/Cursor/Cursor_Goth_Cursor4.png);
}
*:focus{
    cursor: url(../img/Cursor/Cursor_Goth_Cursor4.png);
}
```

Comment: не помогло( всё также

Comment: ```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    cursor: url(../img/Cursor/Cursor_Goth_Cursor4.png), auto;

}
*:hover{
    cursor: url(../img/Cursor/Cursor_Goth_Cursor4.png), auto;
}
*:focus{
    cursor: url(../img/Cursor/Cursor_Goth_Cursor4.png), auto;
}
```

Comment: может как то не правильно вписал команды

Comment: Какие именно закрывающие страницу элементы вы имеете в виду? И для ссылок я бы описывал свойство как `a:hover{...}` а не `*:hover{...}`

Comment: А если `* { cursor: url(../img/Cursor/Cursor_Goth_Cursor4.png), auto !important; }` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подробнее о курсоре можете почитать тут - [Курсор - CSS | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/cursor)

```css
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

* {
  cursor: url('//i.stack.imgur.com/T76l3.png'), default;
}
```

```html
<input value="text input">
<p>Text</p>
<a href="#">Pointer</a><br><br>
<div style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; resize: both; border: 1px solid gray; padding-right: 15px;">Resize</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, но я так понимаю курсор не будет отображаться при наведении на видео в iframe, если это видео с ютуба или какого либо другого источника?

Comment: Да, в вашем вопросе уже кроется ответ - "Курсор не будет изменятся в `iframe`, если он не с вашего домена".